# Find and check an item within a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement, find

My code:

```
for item in lista:
    trade_id = item['tradeId']
    buy_now_price = item['buyNowPrice']
    trade_state = item['tradeState']
    item_id = item['id']
    resource_id = item['resourceId']

print ('ID:' + str(item_id) + '= T: ' + str(resource_id) + ' L: '  + str(starting_bid) + ' | C ' + str(buy_now_price))
```

returns:

```
ID:85357= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100
ID:56639= T: 1645 L: 300 | C 350
ID:53639= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100
ID:10753= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100
ID:04575= T: 1645 L: 150 | C 5000
ID:72146= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 950
```

I need to check if my "Resource_id" = 1642 and put a condition where if he printa with an OK and if not he just list.

Something like this:

```
ID:85357= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100 = Ok
ID:56639= T: 1645 L: 300 | C 350
ID:53639= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100 = Ok
ID:10753= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 1100 = Ok
ID:04575= T: 1645 L: 150 | C 5000
ID:72146= T: 1642 L: 900 | C 950 = Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a little check like this:

```
output = 'ID:' + str(item_id) + '= T: ' + str(resource_id) + ' L: '  + str(starting_bid) + ' | C ' + str(buy_now_price)

if resource_id == 1642:
    output += " = OK"

print(output)
```

Comment: I approve of storing this string in a variable ... I approve less of naming the variable string ... that said +1

Comment: It did not work, only brought only one result!

ID:05199= T: 1645 L: 150 | C 200

Comment: Did you put the print function inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('ID:' + str(item_id) + '= T: ' + str(resource_id) + ' L: '  + str(starting_bid) + ' | C ' + str(buy_now_price) + (" = OK" if int(resource_id) == 1642 else "" ))
```

I guess ....

Comment: Only returned me the correct result, ignoring the previous.